# Tomcat client certificate authentication, client certificate not sent

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, client-certificates

I've add client certificate based authentication on our Tomcat servers.
Both client and server are tomcat servers with internal CA issued certificates.

Each tomcat has its own keystore (PKCS12) containing its private key and certificate and a truststore (JKS) containing the CA public certifiacte.

After stating the Tomcat server for the first time, the authentication fails (results in 403).
Upon restarting the tomcat, the authentication is successful.
I've enabled debugging on the SSL and I've noticed that when the authentication fails, the client does not send its certificate but after restarting it does.

No errors appear in the log files.

Failed authentication log:

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<EMAILADDRESS=x@x.com, CN=x.x.x, OU=x, O=x., L=x, ST=x, C=x>
*** ServerHelloDone
*** Certificate chain
***
*** Found trusted certificate:
```

Succesful authentication log:

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<EMAILADDRESS=x@x.com, CN=x.x.x, OU=x, O=x., L=x, ST=x, C=x>
*** ServerHelloDone
matching alias: tomcat
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
```

Any idea of what's causing it to work on the second try?
Nothing changes on the tomcat servers...

Thanks

Comment: Can't explain why, but the way it works is that if the client can't find a certificate signed directly or indirectly by one of the CAs in the CertificateRequest, it sends an empty chain, as per the failing request. The trace indicates that whichever Tomcat is the server in this exchange has a trust store with only one entry in it, I guess because you only want to trust your internal CA, but that would prevent that Tomcat from accepting client certificates from outside, which may not be your intention.